# Inserting high-res pictures into Excel with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to use VBA to insert a high-res picture into Excel.  When I insert it, the quality is awful.  I found that under File/Options/Advanced, I can set Default Resolution to 'High Fidelity' and 'Do not compress images in file'.  With these settings, I can insert a high resolution picture.

The problem is that I cannot find out how to turn these settings on via VBA.  I have tried using the Macro recorder, and it doesn't record anything. How do I enable these settings programmatically with a new file?

Comment: You find High Fidelity it in the registry  - for Excel 2016 in 
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Excel\Options
And if it is set 
ExcelHighQualityModeForGraphics

The Do not compress seems to be more tricky, because it is set to the workbook.
Maybe some one else can give help.  But have a closer look to the object explorer with unhide feature.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am running Excel 2019, and that registry value appears to have gone away.

Comment: you see it when you check it and close and refresh the registry editor
And you will look in I Guess \17.0\

Comment: Sadly, Picture compression settings aren't supported in the object model which is why you see some folks resorting to using SendKeys.